# Where are stored volumes from docker compose in Azure?

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I haven't find the answer elsewhere, so I try to ask here. Hope it's not silly question for I'm new both to docker compose and Azure.

I'm using docker compose for deploying Web App (actually [bookstack](https://www.bookstackapp.com/)) into Azure. The stack uses few volumes. Everything works just fine, volumes are persistent. Only I'm not able to locate volumes used inside Azure portal. I really need to be able to access these in order to backup or maybe migrate them.

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.21
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=
    - MYSQL_USER=
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
    - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  bookstack:
    image: solidnerd/bookstack:latest
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    environment:
    - DB_HOST=
    - DB_DATABASE=
    - DB_USERNAME=
    - DB_PASSWORD=
    volumes:
    - uploads:/var/www/bookstack/public/uploads
    - storage-uploads:/var/www/bookstack/public/storage
    ports:
    - "8088:80"

volumes:
 mysql-data:
 uploads:
 storage-uploads:
```

Thanks in advance!
Jakub

Comment: pretty sure those would be local to the webapp

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change these lines to use the placeholder variable:

```
- uploads:/var/www/bookstack/public/uploads
- storage-uploads:/var/www/bookstack/public/storage
```

as follows:

```
- ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/uploads:/var/www/bookstack/public/uploads
- ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/storage-uploads:/var/www/bookstack/public/storage
```

You may want to take a look at the FTP file structure to determine where you want to map the files to :)